# Convert tuples to proplists

Tags: erlang

How can I convert tuple from MongoDB

```
{'_id',<<"vasya">>,password,<<"12ghd">>,age,undefined}
```

to proplist

```
[{'_id',<<"vasya">>},{password,<<"12ghd">>},{age,undefined}]
```

Comment: Looks like it's mongodb that should be changed. I have done this exact thing also and it seems to me everyone does. So maybe it should be the mongodb driver doing this after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to basically combine the two consecutive elements of the tuple together, this isn't too hard.  You can use [`element\2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#element-2) to pull elements from tuples.  And [`tuple_size\1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#tuple_size-1) to get the size of the tuple.  Here's a couple of ways to handle this:

```
1> Tup = {'_id',<<"vasya">>,password,<<"12ghd">>,age,undefined}.
{'_id',<<"vasya">>,password,<<"12ghd">>,age,undefined}
2> Size = tuple_size(Tup).            
6
```

You can use a list comprehension for this:

```
3> [{element(X, Tup), element(X+1, Tup)} || X <- lists:seq(1, Size, 2)].
[{'_id',<<"vasya">>},{password,<<"12ghd">>},{age,undefined}]
```

Or you can zip it:

```
4> lists:zip([element(X, Tup) || X <- lists:seq(1, Size, 2)], [element(X, Tup) || X <- lists:seq(2, Size, 2)]).
[{'_id',<<"vasya">>},{password,<<"12ghd">>},{age,undefined}]
```

You can clean up that zip by making a function to handle pulling elements out.

```
slice(Tuple, Start, Stop, Step) ->
    [element(N, Tuple) || N <- lists:seq(Start, Stop, Step)].
```

Then calling this function:

```
5> lists:zip(slice(Tup, 1, Size, 2), Slice(Tup, 2, Size, 2)).
[{'_id',<<"vasya">>},{password,<<"12ghd">>},{age,undefined}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *bson:fields/1* (https://github.com/mongodb/bson-erlang/blob/master/src/bson.erl#L52). **bson** is the dependency of mongodb erlang driver

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could write a simple function to do it:

```
mongo_to_proplist(MongoTuple) ->
    mongo_to_tuple(MongoTuple, 1, tuple_size(MongoTuple)).

mongo_to_proplist(Mt, I, Size) when I =:= Size -> [];
mongo_to_proplist(Mt, I, Size) ->
    Key = element(I, Mt),
    Val = element(I+1, Mt),
    [{Key,Val}|mongo_to_proplist(Mt, I+2, Size)].
```

This is basically what the list comprehension versions are doing but unravelled into an explicit loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not very efficient, so do not use it on large structures, but really simple:

```
to_proplist(Tuple) -> to_proplist1(tuple_to_list(Tuple), []).

to_proplist1([], Acc) -> Acc;
to_proplist1([Key, Value | T], Acc) -> to_proplist1(T, [{Key, Value} | Acc]).
```

If order should for some strange reason be important reverse the proplist in the base case of to_proplist1/2.

Comment: It doesn't have to be tail recursive so `to_proplist_([]) -> []; to_proplist_([K, V | T]) -> [{K,V} | to_proplist_(T)].` because this sort of recursions are fast enough nowadays and tuple already has limited size.

Comment: Indeed it does not have to be tail recursive, but as a general rule using tail recursive versions using accumulating parameters leads to less spiky memory usage. For this particular function, of course if we have a list long enough for memory to matter it would be far to slow.