# Convert proplist to paired tuple

Tags: erlang

This is the reverse of ["Convert tuples to proplists"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816028/convert-tuples-to-proplists).

I've got an Erlang proplist, potentially containing duplicate keys:

```
P = [{foo, "bar"},             % key = string (char list)
      baz, {quux, true},       % both true; one expanded
      {dog, "Rex"},            % this overrides the duplicate below
      {sum, 42},               % key = integer
      {dog, "Fido"},           % overriden above
      {colour, blue},          % key = atom
      {always, false}].        % opposite of baz or quux
```

I'd like to turn it into a paired tuple (suitable for [bson-erlang](https://github.com/mongodb/bson-erlang)) as follows:

```
{foo, "bar",
 baz, true,     % atom => {atom, true} => ..., atom, true, ...
 quux, true,
 dog, "Rex",    % the first one.
 sum, 42,
 colour, blue,
 always, false}
```

So, `[{k1, v1}, {k2, v2}, ...]` is now `{k1, v1, k2, v2, ...}`.

The proplist is expanded; duplicate keys use the correct value (the first, as would be returned by `proplists:get_value/2`). In this case, the order of keys in the resulting tuple doesn't particularly matter.

How do I do this in Erlang?

Comment: Does the order of entries in the result matter? Judging from your own answer below, no.

Comment: Seeing the order **DOES** matter in a proplist then you have to be careful in saying how you intend to search in your tuple. If you intend to scan the tuple to find a key then you must preserve the order of the proplist in the tuple. If you indent to be able to jump in anywhere and get the right value for a key then must remove duplicates before building the tuple.

Comment: Why do you want it in a tuple?

Comment: The order doesn't matter in the tuple, provided that the duplicate proplist entries are discarded, keeping the first.

Comment: And I want it in a tuple, because that's the format that bson-erlang wants it.

Comment: Upon investigation, it looks like `bson:merge` might do what I want, provided I pay attention to the proplist ordering.

Comment: Well, I learned about `lists:flatmap/2` at least ;)

Comment: You know, I happen to be very proud about my answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

The best I've come up with so far is the following:

```
paired_tuple_from_proplist(P) ->
    % This is a hack, but uses the fact that orddict:from_list
    % removes duplicates. Unfortunately, later overrides earlier
    % which is the other way round from proplists. Hence the reverse.
    D = orddict:from_list(lists:reverse(proplists:unfold(P))),
    L = paired_list_from_orddict(D),
    list_to_tuple(L).

paired_list_from_orddict(D) ->
    paired_list_from_orddict(D, []).

paired_list_from_orddict([], Acc) ->
    Acc;    % DON'T reverse the list.
paired_list_from_orddict([{K,V}|Rest], Acc) ->
    paired_list_from_orddict(Rest, [K,V|Acc]).
```

Comment: I thought I had put a function in there to remove entries that are overridden by earlier ones, but apparently not. It was a long time ago. I might need to revisit this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
p([{K,V}|T]) -> [K,V|p(T)];
p([S|T]) -> [S,true|p(T)];
p([]) -> [].
```

Comment: This is definitely the most straight forward way of doing it. You just need to wrap it in a `list_to_tuple`.

Comment: straight but it does not make exactly what Roger is looking for :o), it reverses the order, it is not a tuple, it does not remove duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0):

short, but I am afraid not efficient for long list:

```
5> P = [{foo, "bar"},baz, {quux, true},{dog, "Rex"},{sum, 42},{dog, "Fido"},{colour, blue},{always, false}].

[{foo,"bar"},baz,{quux,true},{dog,"Rex"},{sum,42},{dog,"Fido"},{colour,blue},{always,false}]

6> F = fun({X,Y},{A1,A2}) -> case lists:member(X,A1) of true -> {A1,A2}; _ -> {[X|A1],[X,Y|A2]} end;
          (X,{A1,A2}) -> case lists:member(X,A1) of true -> {A1,A2}; _ ->  {[X|A1],[X,true|A2]} end end.

 #Fun<erl_eval.12.80484245>

7> {_,L2} = lists:foldr(F,{[],[]},P).

{[foo,baz,quux,sum,dog,colour,always],[foo,"bar",baz,true,quux,true,sum,42,dog,"Fido",colour,blue,always,false]}

8> list_to_tuple(L2).

{foo,"bar",baz,true,quux,true,sum,42,dog,"Fido",colour,blue,always,false}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this.

- doesn't respect order
- removes duplicate keys
- keeps the first encountered value
- no hacky stuff ;)

And it's only a single function !
(wrote it as a one-liner, fun could be defined outside the `lists:foldl/3` call for nicer formatting).

```
toPairedList(ListIn) ->
    ListOut = lists:foldl(fun(Key,Acc) ->
                             [Val|_] = proplists:get_all_values(Key,ListIn),
                             [Key,Val | Acc]
                             end
                          ,[]
                          ,proplists:get_keys(ListIn)),
    list_to_tuple(ListOut).
```

---

Damn, I hate these exercises, they're killing my productivity.
Still, a shorter variant, using `lists:flatmap/2`, so there's no need for an accumulator any more.

```
toPairedList(ListIn) ->
    Job = fun(Key) -> [Val|_] = proplists:get_all_values(Key,ListIn),
                      [Key,Val] end,
    list_to_tuple(lists:flatmap(Job ,proplists:get_keys(ListIn))).
```

Result:

```
> toPairedList([{foo, "bar"},baz, {quux, true}, {dog, "Rex"}, {sum, 42}, {dog, "Fido"}, {colour, blue}, {always, false}]).

{colour,blue,always,false,dog,"Rex",quux,true,baz,true,sum,42,foo,"bar"}
```